# setup smtp(without domain) locally for another app (sandstorm.io)

Tags: smtp

Disclaimer: I have barely any infrastructure knowledge, so maybe the obivous already works.
I am trying to setup sandstorm.io on my local machine for testing purposes. It needs an SMTP server to send mails from. Google SMTP for example wont work, since it needs to change the `FROM` field.

During the setup, it prompts me to enter an SMTP host and it's port number.
Well, I don't have any.
My solution to resolve this: Install postfix to work on the local network (or just my machine at first) and let sandstorm use that smtp server to send emails.

My problem: In the setup process, I have to enter a domain name, same goes for all the tutorials. Well, I do not have a domain name? I just want to test it locally, so how do I proceed?

I thought I could just let it be mail.example.com but when I run telnet mail.example.com 25 it responds with telnet: could not resolve mail.example.com/25: Name or service not known
So yeah, that's that. Any hints/tips/ideas/solutions are appreciated.
Edit to clarify: I setup postfix following this guide and stopped after the basic configuration, since I just need the most basic setup for this.

To wrap it up: One app needs an SMTP to send mails from. I want to test this locally, so just on my machine/my local network. Therfore, no DNS (since there is no domain to look for), no Firewall bypassing etc. Is there any simple way to do this?

Update. This is what I have done so far:

- `curl https://install.sandstorm.io | bash`
- install postfix with `apt-get install postfix`
- reconfigure postfix by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix`add exampleDomain.org as domain
- change the `sandstorm.conf`: BASE_URL=http://localhost and WILDCARD_HOST=*.localhost and remove HTTPS_PORT
- `sandstorm admin-token`

What to enter now in step 3) of setting up the E-Mail so that I actually receive the test-mail?

Comment: add this hostname to `/etc/hosts` (will be wise not to use `localhost` as hostname)

Comment: Also have you try to enter IP instead of hostname?

Comment: I understand that i can put an entry with 127.0.0.1 anyName,  but which hostname should I add? the one using in the postfix setup?

Comment: Correct. Of you can any name and reconfigure postfix after that

Comment: I will just update my post, that is easier.

Comment: It depend of which user you use. if its `root` use `root@localhost`

Comment: that results in `Error while trying to send test email: {"code":"EMESSAGE","response":"450","responseCode":450,"command":"DATA"} [other-email-sending-error]`